# HTML Pop up Window in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

How to pop up html popup window in WPF? In Silverlight, I have tried like below which works fine.

```
           HtmlPopupWindowOptions options = new HtmlPopupWindowOptions()
        {
            Directories = false,
            Location = false,
            Menubar = false,
            Status = false,
            Toolbar = false,
            Resizeable = true,
            Width = 1024,
            Height = 640,
        };

        HtmlPage.PopupWindow(new Uri(strUrl), "_blank", options);
```

But in wpf there is no references related to `HtmlPopupWindowOptions` class. How can I show html pop up in WPF?

Comment: I need html pop window not normal wpf pop up.

Comment: There is no such thing in WPF. You may however put a [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) in a WPF popup.